# ec2 as bastion host and its performance

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, subnet

I am having a Redshift in private subnet and an ec2 instance in Public subnet which is just a bastion host for my Redshift. All is working well and I can actually connect to my Redshift through internet (SSH).

Now, I want redo the task in the production environment and I want to choose an ec2 instance (nano, micro etc). I am having a doubt, whether my ec2 instance performance depends on the query data transfer size. That is, lets say my redshift returns a huge amount of data for a query and will ec2 throttle the performance?

Basically, I don't want my ec2 to be a performance bottleneck and I am not sure will it be. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, your instance size won't be a bottleneck for a tunnel connection.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, **you can change the Instance Type** of an Amazon EC2 instance at any time. Just stop the instance, change the Instance Type and start it again. So, start with `t2.nano` and make it bigger if you find any performance problems.

Secondly, your use-case will consume **very little RAM and very little CPU**. You can look at Amazon CloudWatch metrics to monitor CPU utilization and you can use operating system tools to monitor memory (or use [Monitoring Memory and Disk Metrics for Amazon EC2 Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html)).

**Bottom line:** Measure and monitor your existing environment and the production environment. Change Instance Type as necessary. Don't sweat it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will start with the nano and scale it when required.